# VB.net Cannot bind to the new value member. Parameter name: value

Tags: vb.net

I made a procedure for adding data to combo box in vb.net 2010. I got error as i call it many time for different combo box objects. It's error with line `cbo.ValueMember = fldID`​. Anyone here can solve this?
Thanks,
Phearath

```
Public Sub LoadDataToCbo(ByVal cbo As ComboBox, ByVal fldID As String, ByVal fldname As String, ByVal tbl As String)
    Dim strSQL As String = "Select " & fldID & ", " & fldname & " From " & tbl & " Order By " & fldname
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, sqlConnection1)
    If sqlConnection1.State = ConnectionState.Open Then sqlConnection1.Close()
    sqlConnection1.Open()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        cbo.ValueMember = fldID
        cbo.DisplayMember = fldname
        cbo.DataSource = dt
    End If
    sqlConnection1.Close()
```

Comment: Always use sql-parameters instead of string concatenation, no excuses.

Comment: At least tell us what the error is.

Comment: He was telling the the sql thing to help prevent you from having a very easy sql injection attack.  As for the issue, i'm not totally sure what it is, but when it occurs i would check the value of cbo.ValueMember is.  It is hard to be more specific with the details provided.

Comment: i can solve it now coz i passed ValueMember to the same combo box.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I solved it by indicating the table's name in the parameter for the `DataTable()`:

```
Public Sub LoadDataToCbo(ByVal cbo As ComboBox, ByVal fldID As String, ByVal fldname As String, ByVal tbl As String)  

Dim strSQL As String = "Select " & fldID & ", " & fldname & " **From** " &   **tbl** & " Order By " & fldname  
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, sqlConnection1)
    If sqlConnection1.State = ConnectionState.Open Then sqlConnection1.Close()
    sqlConnection1.Open()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dt As New **DataTable(tbl)**
    da.Fill(dt)
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        cbo.ValueMember = fldID
        cbo.DisplayMember = fldname
        cbo.DataSource = dt
    End If
    sqlConnection1.Close()
```